# PySpark dynamic like operations

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-like

I have a PySpark dataframe like this:

```py
data = [{"ID": 1, "Value": 3478},
        {"ID": 2, "Value": 10},
        {"ID": 3, "Value": 3323},
        {"ID": 1, "Value": 2300},
        {"ID": 2, "Value": 40},
        {"ID": 3, "Value": 93},
        {"ID": 1, "Value": 500},
        {"ID": 2, "Value": 50},
        {"ID": 3, "Value": 73}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show(20, False)
# +---+-----+                                                                     
# |ID |Value|
# +---+-----+
# |1  |3478 |
# |2  |10   |
# |3  |3323 |
# |1  |2300 |
# |2  |40   |
# |3  |93   |
# |1  |500  |
# |2  |50   |
# |3  |73   |
# +---+-----+
```

I have another Spark dataframe like this:

```py
final_data = [{"ID": 1, "Value": 1234563478},
              {"ID": 2, "Value": 2134510},
              {"ID": 3, "Value": 789033323}]

final_df = spark.createDataFrame(final_data)
final_df.show(5, False)
# +---+----------+                                                                
# |ID |Value     |
# +---+----------+
# |1  |1234563478|
# |2  |2134510   |
# |3  |789033323 |
# +---+----------+
```

Now my requirement is to filer final_df based on df values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

final_df.filter(F.col("ID") == "1").where(F.col("Value").like('%3478%') | F.col("ID").like('%2300%') | F.col("ID").like('%500%')).show(5, False)
# +---+----------+                                                                
# |ID |Value     |
# +---+----------+
# |1  |1234563478|
# +---+----------+
```

Here from the df values I have manually passed as value to `like` condition.
Is there a dynamic way to call the value of df in final_df. Today I have only 3 values for matching id == 1, tomorrow I might have 10 values. How to set dynamically `like` conditions in PySpark dataframe?

Comment: why can you not use `join()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really expect. Lets try use lists and fstring if you are after declaring variables and having them dynamically picked. If not what you are after, let me know.

```
s='3478'
s1 ='2300'
s2 ='500'
lst=['1']
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

final_df.filter(F.col("ID").isin(lst)).where(F.col("Value").like(f'%{s}%') | F.col("ID").like(f'%{s1}%')| F.col("ID").like(f'%{s2}%')).show(5,False)
```

Comment: s,s1,s2 are dynamic and we never how many values will have. Is there a way of handling where condition with like dynamically?

Comment: Not sure I understood what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You may need some python to create a filter with many dynamic conditions. I assume your df is relatively small, so I use `collect`

```py
filter_list = df.groupBy('ID').agg(F.collect_set('Value').alias('vals')).collect()
row_filter = []
for r in filter_list:
    s = f"ID={r['ID']} AND "
    s += '(' + ' OR '.join([f"Value LIKE '%{v}%'" for v in r['vals']]) + ')'
    row_filter.append(s)
final_df.filter(f"({') OR ('.join(row_filter)})").show()
```

The following must work in Python 2.7, I think.

```py
filter_list = df.groupBy('ID').agg(F.collect_set('Value').alias('vals')).collect()
row_filter = []
for r in filter_list:
    s = "ID=" + str(r['ID']) + " AND "
    s += '(' + ' OR '.join(["Value LIKE '%" + str(v) + "%'" for v in r['vals']]) + ')'
    row_filter.append(s)
final_df.filter("(" + ") OR (".join(row_filter) + ")").show()
```

Comment: my python version is 2.7.15 and it's giving syntax error for s = f"ID={r['ID']} AND ". Please advise on this. Many thanks for you kind support.

Comment: @HadoopUser - please try now the other version.